# Is it true that if $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ converges uniformly to$f$, and each $f_i$ has period P, then $f$ has period P?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

And if we add that each $f_i$ is continuous?

Comment: I don't think you even need that each $f_i$ is continuous. What have you tried? It should be a classical $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.

Comment: It is true (not hard to prove either, think about what it means for each $f_i$ to have period $P$), and if the $f_i$ are continuous then so is $f$ by uniform continuity. (why?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even pointwise convergence is sufficient. Indeed, suppose that each $f_n$ has period $P$. Take an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$
f(x + P) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} f_n(x + P) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)
$$
where we used that $f_n$ is periodic in the second equality. This shows that $f$ itself has period $P$.

*Note:* By having period $P$ I mean that $f(x + P) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I do not mean that there cannot be a $P' < P$ which also satisfies this equation. If by having period $P$ you mean $f(x + P) = f(x)$ and that there is no $P' < P$ such that $f(x + P') = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then the statement is no longer true (not even for uniform convergence).

Comment: Indeed, the functions in the sequence $\frac 1 n \cos x$ have period $2 \pi$, but the limit is $0$.